# Speed test Linq2SQL v Entiry Framework

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

Has anyone compared the speed of performance between LINQ to SQL against the Entity Framework?

I have heard that LINQ to SQL is 4 times faster than the Entity Framework, but I've never seen any bench marks or sample application proving this.

Comment: there are many questions on SO discussing similiar topics

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's quite a full investigation [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/03/27/ado-net-entity-framework-performance-comparison.aspx), although it is an MSDN blog so potentially biased I suppose.

Comment: The article is not using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: You will find in this:http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/02/11/exploring-the-performance-of-the-ado-net-entity-framework-part-2.aspx